# After setting an it() timeout, my next test does not load

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm interested in setting spec level timeouts so my automation can resume past failed specs quicker, rather than having to wait for the global jasmine timeout to trigger.

I've recently discovered one can supply the timeout argument in milliseconds as an argument to the spec's it() function.

Using that, I DO get the timeout error, but the next test does not load, I'm just stuck with:

"A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow."

Here's what my code looks like:

```
it('Verify login', function () {

    baseFuncs.login();

    browser.driver.sleep(3000);

},12000);
```

I suspect for some reason after this spec timeout, the global jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL timeout is still waiting, and respected?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example test with multiple `it`s demonstrating the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I have one it() per spec, so normally protractor will just run the very next spec (alphabetically), but won't run the next spec in line. I run multiple specs either by passing the "--suite" parameter, or in my protractor config file and setting spect to: specs: ['spec/a_sign_in/*.js']

Comment: Here's two separate specs you can place in the same folder and run. The first should hit the timeout (it does), but then the second spec won't run.

Comment: describe('quick test - smoke 1', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {

    });

    it('foo - bar', function () {
        browser.driver.sleep(15000);
    },10000);

    afterEach(function () {
        console.log("done with 1")
    });

});

Comment: describe('quick test - smoke 2', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {

    });

    it('foo - bar', function () {
        browser.driver.sleep(10000);
    },15000);

    afterEach(function () {
        console.log("done with 2")
    });

});